# Conditional Pop up warning when value changed in another tab

Tags: excel, vba

our spreadsheet it used to monitor resource status,

where as each project allocation for different resource is in tab "Allocation"

in a separate tab "Capacity report" all the allocation gets summed up in % =SUMIF(Allocation!$F$10:$F$498,'Capacity Report'!$D5,Allocation!CH$10:CH$498).

I would like to set up a warning message box "employee has reached capacity" when number summed up > 140% in Capacity report, when project manager enter number in the Allocation tab

thank you!
David

Comment: [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt) and [research must be done to ask a good question.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Worksheet_Change - put your code there (a simple 'if' should do the trick).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value > 140 Then

        MsgBox "Warning"

    End If

End Sub
```